# django-nvd3 load_chart tag evaluates to False in output HTML and no chart is displayed

Tags: python, django, charts, django-templates

I'm trying to implement a `pieChart` using **django-nvd3**. However, the output html of `{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}` evaluates to `False`. Resultantly (most likely) the chart fails to appear. Below is the **view.py**, **django template** and **html output**.

#### View.py

```
def results(request, nlm_id, time):
    journal = Journal.objects.get(nlm_id = nlm_id)
    stats = return_week(nlm_id, time, PLATFORMS)

    chartdata = {'x': PLATFORMS, 'y': stats}
    charttype = "pieChart"
    chartcontainer = 'piechart_container'
    data = {
        'charttype': charttype,
        'chartdata': chartdata,
        'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
        'extra': {
            'x_is_date': False,
            'x_axis_format': '',
            'tag_script_js': True,
            'jquery_on_ready': True,
        }
    }
    return render(request, 'journals/results.html', {'journal': journal, 
        'stats': stats, 'time': time, 'data': data})
```

#### Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}                                                             
{% load staticfiles %}                                                                 
{% load nvd3_tags %}  

<head>
{% block style %}                                                                            
    {{ block.super }}                                                                    
    {% include_chart_jscss %}                                                            
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}
{% endblock %}           
</head>

<body>
{% block content %}
    {% include_container chartcontainer 400 600 %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

#### Output HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>False</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=""><svg style="width:600px;height:400px;"></svg></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe, x and y must have the same dimension?

Comment: I have the same problem. `{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}` return `False` when `data` is embedded in another dict. You have to use `return render(request, 'test.html', data)` but I don't know how to pass variables with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to pass the variables `charttype`, `chartdata`, `chartcontainer`, and `extra` directly like this:

```
context = {
    'charttype': charttype,
    'chartdata': chartdata,
    'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
    'extra': {
        'x_is_date': False,
        'x_axis_format': '',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': False,
        },
    'journal': journal, 
    'stats': stats,
    'time': time,
    }

return render(request, 'journals/results.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and I fixed it when I changed `{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}`
to `{% load_chart data.charttype data.chartdata data.chartcontainer data.extra %}`
and similarly `{% include_container chartcontainer 400 600 %}` to `{% include_container data.chartcontainer 400 600 %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your load_chart in an if statement which checks that there is chartdata, eg:

```
{% if chartdata %}
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra %}
{% endif %}
```